# MVVM Light SL5 missing SimpleIoc

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

After upgrading to MvvmLight for Silverlight 5 the namespace GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc is missing which means that registration of view model using SimpleIoc is also missing.

Any hints or solutions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Ups. Just got the answer from Laurent Bugnion. I installed V3 (stable) not V4 (beta).
V3 does not contain SimpleIoc.